# Не могу использовать данные, которые получил из JSON файла удаленно

Tags: json, ios, swift

Есть ссылка с JSON файлом. Конструкция в нем такая:

devices - это массив с 12 элементами
user - просто данные в количестве 1 шт.

Model:

```
struct Devices: Decodable {
    var devices: [Device]
    var user: User
    
}

struct Device: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var deviceName: String
    var intencity: Int?
    var mode: String?
    var temperature: Int?
    var position: Int?
    var productType: String
    
}

struct User: Decodable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var address: Adress
    var birthDate: Int
}

struct Adress: Decodable {
    var city: String
    var postalCode: Int
    var street: String
    var streetCode: String
    var country: String
    
}
```

Есть метод, благодаря которому мы получаем данные

```
class DataViewModel {
    
    var dataVM = [Devices]()
    
    func fetchData(completion: @escaping(Devices) -> Void) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "ТУТ ССЫЛКА НА JSON файл") else { return }
        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            guard let jsonData = data else { return }
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do {
                
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Devices.self, from: jsonData)
                completion(decodedData)
                
            } catch {
                
                print("Error decoding data")
                
            }
            
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

Данные про пользователя я могу спокойно выводить на экран вот так:

```
modelManager.fetchData { (devices) in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                
                print(devices.devices.count) // Пишет 12, значит данные есть
                
                self.nameTextView.text.append(contentsOf: "\(devices.user.firstName + " " + devices.user.lastName)")
                self.cityAddresView.text.append(contentsOf: "\(devices.user.address.street + ", " + devices.user.address.streetCode)")
                self.postalCode.text.append(contentsOf: "\(String(devices.user.address.postalCode))")
                self.cityNameView.text.append(contentsOf: "\(devices.user.address.city)")
                self.countryNameView.text.append(contentsOf: "\(devices.user.address.country)")
                self.birthDateView.text.append(contentsOf: "\(devices.user.birthDate)")
                
                self.setupLayout()
            }
        }
```

, но вот уже devices.devices оно не может отобразить. Но я точно уверен что эти данные загружены, но я не могу их по какой-то причине отобразить. Буду рад помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я как понял вам нужно что-то подобное

```
        modelManager.fetchData { (devices) in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                guard let device = devices.devices.first else {
                    return
                }
                
                // или
                
                for device in devices.devices {
                    // ...
                }
            
            }
        }
```